# Excel: VBA to lookup with multiple criteria and concatenate multiple data ranges into single cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, concatenation

```
     A        B            C                ....      U
1    Length   Type         Program                    Category

2    <20m     Patrol       Ecuador (CG)               Red
3    <20m     Patrol       Kenya (Police)             Amber
4    <20m     Patrol       Uruguay                    Red
5    <20m     MCMV         France (Drone)             Red
6    <20m     Amphibious   Peru (ACV)                 Red
7    20-29m   Patrol       Bahrain (CG)               Amber
8    20-29m   Patrol       Denmark                    Amber
9    20-29m   Patrol       Latvia (BG)                Red
10   20-29m   Patrol       Latvia (CG)                Red
11   20-29m   Patrol       Lithuania (BG)             Amber
12   20-29m   Patrol       Norway                     Amber
..
```

The result that I would like to get is:

```
      A         B                      C                        D 
  1   Length    Category Red           Category Amber           Category Green

  2   <20m      Patrol - Ecuador (CG)  Patrol - Kenya (Police)
                MCMV - France (Drone)
                etc....
  3   20-29m    Patrol - Latvia (BG)   Patrol - Bahrain (CG)
                Patrol - Latvia (CG)   Patrol - Denmark
                etc....                etc....
  4   30-39m

  ...
```

I've seen several concatenating VBA questions on here but none that involve concatenating two distinct ranges of data (columns B & C). Ideally the results are separated by lines rather than rows (ie Alt + Enter) but this may not be possible.
Any help  appreciated, thanks.

Edit: To clarify, second piece of code is in a separate worksheet.

Comment: That would be an Pivot table with Concatenate agregate function. As far as I know, it doesn't exist in Excel - I wish it does. In VBA it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've been working on amending the code found here to suit my purposes.

Comment: I've been working on amending the code found here to suit my purposes.https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2723-excel-concatenate-based-on-criteria.html. Unfortunately, the use of multiple criteria AND having to concatenate multiple data ranges probably makes the code so different it's easier to start from scratch. I'm a complete novice at VBA which isn't ideal either.

Comment: I've got some code that could do this I think, but this place prefers you to make an effort yourself, post what you've tried and go from there.

Comment: Thanks SJR, both versions work quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It assumes a second sheet for the results

```
Sub x()

Dim vIn(), vOut(), i As Long, n As Long, vCol, j As Long

vIn = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(vIn, 1), 1 To 4)
vCol = Array("Red", "Amber", "Green")

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 2 To UBound(vIn, 1)
        j = Application.Match(vIn(i, 4), vCol, 0) + 1
        If Not .Exists(vIn(i, 1)) Then
            n = n + 1
            vOut(n, 1) = vIn(i, 1)
            vOut(n, j) = vIn(i, 2) & " - " & vIn(i, 3) & vbLf
            .Add vIn(i, 1), n
        ElseIf .Exists(vIn(i, 1)) Then
            vOut(.Item(vIn(i, 1)), j) = vOut(.Item(vIn(i, 1)), j) & vIn(i, 2) & " - " & vIn(i, 3) & vbLf
        End If
    Next i
End With

With Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(n, 4)
    .ClearContents
    .Value = vOut
End With

End Sub
```